# How to pass a specific action to a viewmodel to execute on a button press?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to setup this scenario.

The basic premise is this. I have a message window, with couple of text fields and button, controlled by a viewmodel and a model. Originally window is displayed with showdialog() with button invisible while some background checks are going on.

If a an error occurs i would like the text in the window to change accordingly and a button become visible. I would also like this button to execute a specific action, a delegate or a static somewhere.

I would like to be able to pass this action to the viewmodel to be executed. The reason is i want to be reuse this window for different screen and button actions may change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Define a command in your ViewModel(as a property with INotifyPropertyChanged).

2. Bind your button to this command:

   Command={Binding MyCommand}

where MyCommand=property of yours viewmodel.

3. In case you need to change command action, just set property MyCommand to the implementation of command you are currently in need of.

Comment: So creating any routed command and passing it to my model should do the trick?

Comment: Would be better to implement your own ICommand , RoutedCommand is suitable but gives too tight coupling to presentation layer.

Comment: I found part of the answer right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060192/command-to-call-method-from-viewmodel Another part was implementing a function in ViewModel and calling it through type             ActionCommand.ExecuteFunc = new Action<object>( (delegate(object o)
            {
                this.GetType().GetMethod(Model.ClickCommand).Invoke(this, null);
            })); I am passing the name of the function through the model. Next I want to see if i can actually send a whole action through the model. Thank you all for help.

Comment: Just a side note, your `ICommand` doesn't have to be with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It will work without as well.